# construct a data frame in R from combining information of two columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of two columns: `true.de.status` and `decision.de`. The dataset is reproducible as below:

```
dat = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(100L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("true.de.status", "decision.de"
)))
```

The first several rows of `dat` are:

```
       true.de.status decision.de
  [1,]              0           0
  [2,]              0           0
  [3,]              1           1
  [4,]              0           1
  [5,]              1           0
  [6,]              0           0
  [7,]              1           1
  [8,]              1           0
```

Now I hope to draw a plot with x-axis the number of genes (i.e. total number of rows in `dat`) and y-axis the number of true positives. The x-axis is easy to determine: `seq(0,100)` will give me 0, 1, ..., 100 genes. For the y-axis, I need to calculate based on the two columns `true.de.status` and `decision.de`: as I go through each row, I can calculate the true positives as the number of genes (row) increases. For example,

```
first 1 gene included: True positive (TP) = 0
first 2 genes included: TP = 0
first 3 genes included: TP = 1 (since both columns have 1 and they match)
first 4 genes included: TP = 1 (`decision.de` is 1, but `true.de.status` is 0, so it is a false positive)
first 5 genes included: TP = 1 (two columns don't match)
......
```

Is there an easy way to manipulate the `dat` data frame, and return a vector of the same length as `dim(dat)[1]` with the number of True positives? Thanks!

Comment: Just so we are clear, that is not a dataframe but rather a matrix. Which was why I needed to use "[" rather than "$" to access its columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you wanted:

```
plot( cumsum( dat[ , "true.de.status"] == 1 &
              dat[ , "decision.de"] == 1) , 
      type="s")
```

(By default the x values will be `1:100`. If you wanted points or lines you can change the type argument. Obviously you could use `vec <- ...` to assign that cumsum value to a name)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
df <- as.data.frame(dat)
df$TP <- cumsum(as.numeric(df$true.de.status == 1 & df$decision.de == 1))
```

This will return cumulative count of instances where both columns have 1 and they match.

Comment: Perhaps OP wants the `cumsum` of your TP?

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why the last two examples he provided were counted as true positives...